# Como eu faria para o usuário cadastrar um nome e uma senha qualquer para logar?

Tags: python

Nesse código, como eu faria para o usuário cadastrar um nome e uma senha qualquer para logar?

```
#Python 3.8.5
inicial = input("Olá!")
inicial2 = input("Você é um novo usuário?")

answer = input("Responda 'Sim' ou 'Não': ") 
if answer == "Sim" or "sim":
    print("Vamos nos cadatrar!")

    def registrar_usuario():
          cadastro_usuario = input("\n\nUsuário: ")
    def registrar_senha():
          cadastro_senha = input("\n\nSenha: ")
          print("Cadatro realizado com sucesso!")
          print("Entre com seu usuário e senha!")
usuario = input("\n\nUsuário: ") 
senha = input("Senha: ") 

#Nessa parte quero que o programa use o nome de usuario e a senha fornecida pelo usuario.
if usuario == ' '   and senha == ' ':
    print("Login realizado")
```

Comment: Bem vinda ao SO-pt, por favor leia o [manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/13561), principalmente a seção [achar que nós faremos o seu trabalho todo de graça](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/13561)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mudei algumas coisinhas e adaptei pra algo funcional. `dados_login_e_senha`é um dicionário que serve pra associar um valor à outro: Uma senha à um login nesse caso.

```
def registrar_usuario(dados):
      cadastro_usuario = input("\n\nUsuário: ")
      if cadastro_usuario in dados:
          print("ERRO! Ja existe um usuario com esse nome")
          return
      cadastro_senha = input("\n\nSenha: ")
      print("Cadatro realizado com sucesso!")
      dados[cadastro_usuario] = cadastro_senha

dados_login_e_senha = {}
answer = input("Você é um novo usuário? Responda 'Sim' ou 'Não': ")

if answer == "Sim" or answer == "sim": 
    print("Vamos nos cadatrar!")
    registrar_usuario(dados_login_e_senha)

usuario = input("Entre com seu usuario: ")
senha = input("Informe a senha: ")
if usuario in dados_login_e_senha:
    if dados_login_e_senha[usuario] == senha:
        print("Login efetuado")
    else:
        print("Senha incorreta")
else:
    print("Nao existe nenhum cadastro com esse nome de usuario")
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda! Faltou só um "if" na parte "IF cadastro_usuario in dados:". Mas estou conseguindo desenvolver meu programa

Comment: ops, foi mesmo rsrs! vou editar

Comment: Seria bom deixar claro que com esse método todos os usuários e senhas vão desaparecer quando o programa for encerrado.

Comment: @bfavaretto Em algum momento eu falei que os dados persistiriam? Caso não tenha dado conta, ela está começando a programar agora e a dúvida dela foi sobre `como cadastrar?`, algo relacionado apenas a lógica de como fazer. Em nenhum momento ela perguntou: `como faço para que este usuário e senha sirvam para futuras inicializações?` Eu dei o exemplo de uma função que fazia o que ela queria. Ela não perguntou nada sobre banco de dados ou arquivos. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Você precisará criar um mecanismo de persistência (não volátil), por exemplo, um banco de dados (MySql, Postgree, Oracle, etc) ou um simples arquivo local de texto (*.txt), onde os métodos `registrar_usuário` e `registrar_senha` irão salvar nesse mecanismo.

Posteriormente, você precisará alterar esse trecho abaixo para buscar no seu mecanismo de persistência e conferir se os dados "batem".

```py
if usuario == USUARIO_SALVO and senha == SENHA_SALVA:
    print("Login realizado")
```

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda!